# How to resize vector drawable to device font size

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

Is it possible to set a vector drawable to automatically resize itself based on device's set font size? Whenever I change the font size in the Settings menu, the vector drawable never seems to adapt it's size and always stays the same but yet the text does without fail.

**Drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:height="48dp" android:width="48dp" android:viewportHeight="24" android:viewportWidth="24">
    <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" android:pathData="M7.41,7.84L12,12.42l4.59,-4.58L18,9.25l-6,6 -6,-6z"/>
</vector>
```

**Small font size**

[image]

**Normal font size**

[image]

**Large font size**

[image]

**Huge font size**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sp` units in the definition of the vector drawable. The whole point of the `sp` unit is that `1sp` == `1dp` when the font size is normal, but `1sp` is more than `1dp` when the font size is scaled up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="48sp" <!-- use sp here instead of dp -->
    android:width="48sp"  <!-- use sp here instead of dp -->
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M7.41,7.84L12,12.42l4.59,-4.58L18,9.25l-6,6 -6,-6z"/>

</vector>
```

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of the padding so that the top of the arrow is the same as the top of the `TextView`?

Comment: That padding is built into the vector asset itself. The `viewportWidth` and `viewportHeight` attributes define the size of the "canvas" the vector is drawn on, but the vector only fills a rectangle that's 12 units wide and 7.5 units tall.

Comment: You can change the `pathData` to `M1.41,0l4.59,4.58l4.59,-4.58l1.41,1.41l-6,6l-6,-6z` and change the viewport width/height to `12`/`7.41` to get rid of the "padding". You'll have to decide how large you want the default size to be (the width/height attrs); previously they were simply double the viewport width/height.

Answer (score 1):

- As previous answer use sp instead of dp ,,
- sp more suitable for text
- dp more suitable for pictures